# Connect to Azure function slots from Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-logic-apps

I have an Azure Function with 2 slots. From my Logic App, I want to connect to a function residing in the second slot of the function. I am using the Azure Function connection in Logic App to do the same but its only connecting to the Primary slot function.

A secondary solution would be to call the Function's URL directly from the Logic App using the HTTP connector, but I was wondering if there is some way how I can connect using the Azure Function connector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Azure Function slots is in preview, with slots enabled Logic App integration will not work as expected. PFB the screen shot from Azure portal itself for reference. One work around would be to call the function URL using Http Connector as you have mentioned.

[image: Azure Function Slots preview]

Comment: Not what I was expecting but need to live with it.